# MySQL Join excluding certain records?

Tags: sql, mysql, outer-join

i'm trying to build a join, but I can't get it to work in MySQL, I know there must be a way.

I have two tables: **1. `Setting`** and **2. `User_Setting`** (and ofcourse **`User`** but that won't be needed here).

**Structure**

```
Setting.setting_id
Setting.description
Setting.value_type
Setting.default_value

User_Setting.user_id
User_Setting.setting_id
User_Setting.value
```

I want to select ALL `Setting` records, and join `User_Setting` where there is a value. Classical outer join i would believe?

I have this query:

```
SELECT
`User_Setting`.`user_id`,
`User_Setting`.`value`,
`Setting`.`setting_id`,
`Setting`.`default_value`,
`Setting`.`value_type`,
FROM
`User_Setting`
Right Join `Setting` ON `User_Setting`.`setting_id` = `Setting`.`setting_id`
WHERE
`User_Setting`.`user_id` IS NULL OR
`User_Setting`.`user_id` =  1;
```

But this doesn't work if a `User` with `user_id` 2 has a `User_Setting` record present for a certain `setting_id`, but the `User` with `user_id` 1 hasn't got that `setting_id` record stored...

**Does anybody have a query where ALL settings will be retrieved, with `user_id` and `value` NULL if the `User_Setting` record doesn't exist?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (if you want to check that the user exists)

```
SELECT  `User_Setting`.`user_id`,
        `User_Setting`.`value`,
        `Setting`.`setting_id`,
        `Setting`.`default_value`,
        `Setting`.`value_type`,
FROM    user
CROSS JOIN
        setting
LEFT JOIN
        user_setting
ON      user_setting.user_id = user_id
        AND user_setting.setting_id = setting.setting_id
WHERE   user_id = 1
```

or this (if you don't want to check that the user exists):

```
SELECT  `User_Setting`.`user_id`,
        `User_Setting`.`value`,
        `Setting`.`setting_id`,
        `Setting`.`default_value`,
        `Setting`.`value_type`,
FROM    setting
LEFT JOIN
        user_setting
ON      user_setting.user_id = 1
        AND user_setting.setting_id = setting.setting_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually add a condition to the `WHERE` clause to check that the primary if in the table being joined is not null.